# Loading image while JavaScript function(s) run

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to show a loading image while a JavaScript function is running. I have one that takes about 2-5 seconds, would be nice if i could have something like the jQuery-ajax function

```
$("#loading").bind("ajaxStart", function(){
    $(this).attr("style", "visibility: visible")
}).bind("ajaxStop", function(){
    $(this).attr("style", "visibility: hidden")
});
```

clarification edit:

The idea is that every time a JavaScript function runs and takes over, say 3/4 of a second, the loading image would be displayed. It really has nothing to do with this ajax function, just the same principle of always catching a running JavaScript and timing it.

Thanks!

Comment: By the way `@(...).show()` and `$(...).hide()` are the jquery methods for visibility.

Comment: @Aren thanks for the catch..don't know why I'm doing it this way.

Comment: @thomas Just to be clear, jQuery show and hide methods set the element's "display" attribute to "none" or "block" (or whatever it was before it was "none").  This is a little different than what you're doing here, which is setting the visibility attribute.  One time this difference come into play is when you want to get the dimensions of the image without showing it, which won't work if the display is set to "none".

Comment: @JoshNoe Good catch, yes `visibility` doesn't collapse the element. I just glanced at it and assumed hide/show was what he was looking for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well then... After you commented, that changes everything.

You cannot have it automatically show when *any javascript runs* because there is no real hook for that. You can however leverage jquery custom events through the use of [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) and [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) using your own custom event.

```
function myFunctionThatDoesSomething() {
  $('body').trigger('Custom.BeginWork');

  // Do Something ...

  $('body').trigger('Custom.EndWork');
}
```

Although **long running operations should probably be done asynchronously** so they don't block on the event:

```
$("#Something").click(function() {
   $('body').trigger('Custom.BeginWork');
   setTimeout(function() { DoWorkFunction(/* you can pass params here if you need */); }, 0); 
   // Causes it to be executed in the background 0ms from now
});

function DoWorkFunction() {
   // Stuff...

   $('body').trigger('Custom.EndWork');
}
```

Then register a `.bind()` event much like `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxStop()`

```
$('#Working').bind('Custom.StartWork', function() {
  $(this).show();
});

$('#Working').bind('Custom.EndWork', function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Here is a [working jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UtUFV/2/).

---

Update:

In [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JYAdp/) you've done a double `setTimeout`. Here:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        // Call Operation Here
        try { setTimeout(function () { LongRunningOperation(10000);  }, 1000);
        }
        finally
        {
            $("body").trigger('Custom.End');
        }
    }, 50); // 50ms delay because some browsers *cough*IE*cough* are slow at rendering dom changes
```

What this translates to is:

[image: Diagram]

So the `Custom.End` event is getting fired after **scheduling** the long running function to run, not when it completes. `setTimeout` is *asynchronous* and non-blocking.

Comment: No, I'm just using the ajax thing as an example, I'm just looking for something that will show a loading image whenever javascript runs. thinking sensibly, probably only if it takes over 3/4 of a second.. That wasn't clear from my question

Comment: `whenever javascript runs` `3/4 of a second` How many thousands of lines of JS are you running? Your browser would freeze up unless you're talking about ajax/loading other DOM elements asynchronously. Unless you're talking about `timeOut`/`interval`s or animations. Provide sample code or link to a page that takes more than a couple miliseconds to execute your pieces of code which aren't async.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté My Answer was originally different because I mid-interpreted his question. I think he wants the same thing for long-running operations that may be computational in nature vs. waiting for a ajax response. I think the 3/4th of a second is more of a guideline for himself a UX concern, such that if the user has to wait more than 3/4th of a second he wants a visual indicator that work is being done.

Comment: Alright, I see. I just don't see how that applies to non-ajax non-async functions, as the browser would simply hang until the function is processed. Nevertheless I'll +1 for your effort.

Comment: Can you show me how to implement this with just a simple script that i want to show the load with. say, `for ( var i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) { document.write('i is ' + i + '<br>'); }​` thank you.

Comment: @thomas I added a jsFiddle example.

Comment: that is indeed very helpful and cool. Thank you! I tried adding the 3/4 second delay option by doing a jquery delay to the show() function `status.delay(500).show();`, but to no avail. where would I put that?

Comment: The delay has to happen before you start executing the long running function because it'll often block the reflow process. (Note how all the i = 1, i = 2, etc... show up at once. This is because the tab isn't given any time to reflow / render the document). Some Browsers are quick enough that they can render things in time but that's why my example has the 50ms delay on the anonymous function.

Comment: tried this `try
            {
                setTimeout(function () {
                LongRunningOperation(10000); // Can Pass Arguments
                }, 1000);`  still doesn't work exactly as planned..

Comment: @Aren http://jsfiddle.net/JYAdp/  working only flashes on the screen momentarily, then disappears. then the function writes the values to the screen

Comment: @Aren this is really brilliant. Thank you so much for sketching it out for me like this. I guess my only remaining questions is where _can i_ put the timeout so that it ... well..not so it blocks the function, but so that it triggers when I intend it to, after a few seconds into the javascript function? a third function that sets another timeout before _then_ activating the Custom.start? Thanks!!

Comment: The problem is your long running operation is going to block the browser's rendering pass. The best way to optimize this so there's cycles to show/hide things is to use a HtmlFragment (DOM) or a Container DIV in jQuery. Basically instead of writing to the document, create a div in memory `var container = $("<div></div>")` and just append your changes to it. When you're done add `container.html()` to your page body and it'll add the resulting DOM quickly. This way events fired while it's working on building the result should be able to execute. Also your function will probably be faster.

Comment: @Aren I appreciate all the time you put in on this, unfortunately I've gotten in above my head, and I don't really follow what you mean! Thanks for all the help though! :)

Comment: Really? Only 5 upvotes for this? The answer is clear, with a diagram, and a working fiddle!

Comment: very good answer, helped me. I wonder how I can deduplicate code if I reuse this setTimeout function multiple times. Tried to put it all in a function but i think it messes the asynchronous part